# Android: URL for playing music via HTTP streaming

Tags: android, url

I write Android app and I want to playing music from a remote URL via HTTP streaming. In official tuttorial is showed this code:

`String url = "http://........"; // your URL here`
`MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();`
`mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);`
`mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);`
`mediaPlayer.prepare(); // might take long! (for buffering, etc)`
`mediaPlayer.start();`

But I don't know what kind of URL I should use. Can you show me example of URL that I should use for playing music via HTTP streaming?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an URL, simply an URL. Something like "http://www.adomain.com/music/The%20music.mp3".

And change prepare() to prepareAsync() because this might take long.

Comment: Hello, hjw. The issue is that I can't get [b]valid[/b] URL. I try to use http://www.vorbis.com/music/Epoq-Lepidoptera.ogg from google tutorial: it correct open in browser but when I have invoked setDataSource(url) I catch java.io.IOException: setDataSource failed.: status=0x80000000. I googled and find meaning of this error: file at which points the this path is not valid.

Comment: And you did add it with http:// prefix? E.g. http :// www.vorbis.com / music / Epoq-Lepidoptera.ogg (remove spaces).

Comment: I just tried it with my Android Music Player (http://t.co/iNLqNqM). Did enter your link into the source directly and it worked immediately .

Comment: On Android Music Player it is work fine but he load it in storage before start playing.

Comment: That was not your original question. IMO this topic is answered.